# Do forward slashes (/) always mean directories?

Tags: asp.net, iis

In the context of ASP.NET ans IIS can I have forward slashes in my URL and use those as query strings instead of them indicating directories ?

For example `https://www.reddit.com/r/politics/comments/6xxr0a/sanders_trump_ending_daca_one_of_the_ugliest_and/?utm_content=comments&utm_medium=hot&utm_source=reddit&utm_name=all` (chosen as currently top 1 in /r/all and for no other reason)

I don't believe that there's folder /r and inside it is folder /politics that contains folder /comments that has folder /6xxr0a and so on.

Is it possible to mimic such behavior using asp.net ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no slashes doesn't always mean directories.

Long answer: Read [ASP.NET Routing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx). There you will find all about routes and how you can achieve something like reddit.